# How can I send a message to another program without triggering WM_MOUSELEAVE after WM_LBUTTONDOWN?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, messaging

I have 2 applications (one of which I don't have access to code) and I need to press a button via messaging on the app I don't have access to.

The problem is that the button animates as if I've clicked on it, but the expected action does not occur, it does if I click it manually just not when I click it through SendMessage like this;

```
SendMessage(wndHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MousePosition)
```

can anyone help?

Comment: coudl you add more details ? Like how to you get `wndHandle`, `MousePosition` ? I would suggest you try doing this with an application you create only for this purpose, that way you will be able to understand how and which messages and being received.

Comment: And also, you must trigger Button UP after this one, because when you leave the mouse button down in Windows, it doesn't click the button...

Comment: Well the button I have doesn't have a wndHandle, and thr mouse position is just hard coded co-ordinates